# CloudFormation custom resources problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have been trying to use CloudFormation for tasks like ACM certificates, DNS delegations and SES domains.  Most of these items seem to require a custom resource to do what CFN cannot do natively.  I've found many examples of lambda custom resources and got them to work.

My issues come when I need to update or potentially delete a stack.  The custom resources turn into massive issues.  The custom resources timeout and cause all sorts of problems.  Is this just an issue with how they are coded?  Are there other gotcha behaviors of custom resources which can be shared?

Example:
https://medium.com/poka-techblog/verify-domains-for-ses-using-cloudformation-8dd185c9b05c

Comment: Related discussion and custom resource example for ACM certificates: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/31#issuecomment-517084086

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I intentionally avoided code because this behavior hasn't been with just 1 or 2 custom resources.  It seems to be across various ones that are popular in online articles.

Comment: Yes, it requires very careful coding and exception handling and it's hard to get right. I tried creating a [framework](https://github.com/CloudSnorkel/cfm-reslib) for this to make it simpler. Hopefully it can help someone.